# session_start is failing to create session ID

Tags: php, laravel-5, memcached

I'm working in PHP 7.1 with Laravel 5.5. The error thrown is:

> Failed to create session ID: memcached (path: localhost:11211)

The code causing the error is:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start(); // error on this line
}
```

My sessions are supposed to be files, which are successfully created:

```
/config/session.php
  'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/config/cache.php
  'driver' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

/.env
  CACHE_DRIVER=file
  SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

So I can't figure out why memcached is pitching a fit or why `session_start()` is unable to return the ID it is clearly creating.

Comment: Look if you have any entry for SESSION_DRIVER in the .env file

Comment: Just added it to the question. It is set to `file`.

Comment: Take a look at `config/cache.php` and check if there is any entry for memchached

Comment: The cache driver is `file` as well

Comment: There is a memcached array defined in the stores array.

Comment: Maybe your session is already created or you call session_start() too late?#

Comment: @Blackbam - after wrapping in `if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)`, the problem still exists. I will add this to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you check if php session save.path is using memcached?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your memcached config? The session will go wrong if php-fpm cant connect to memcached.